# How can I get notified for other's question that i'm interested in whenever it get answer

Tags: support

I searched option for getting notified when some questions asked by others which I'm interested in get answer(s). I came across this situation every time I found some intelligent(good) question and even I'd like to know the answer. The conditions are.
1. I like the question and I've not left any comments to that post.
2. Even I've not tried to answer that question.

But can I get notified when it get some answers,
1. Even if they don't address my name using @ ( if in case i've left any comment).
I saw this symbol at the right bottom of the question page that question feed

[image: snapshot]

If I go to question feed it ask for subscription to google and those options are strange. I just want to get notified within Ubuntu forum(like we get notificaions) for answers answered to some others question. Please suggest even if there is any alternative method. Please help me.

Comment: As you suggested @Mostafa Shahverdy. Can you help me now ?

Comment: Just favorite the question by clicking the star!